# Using tr to replace non-alpha characters with '-' is adding an extra character to end of string

Tags: bash, tr

I have the following string `hello/world`
I want to replace the `/` with `-` to get `hello-world`

I've tried the following: http://rextester.com/NMIOL63413

```
$ echo hello/world | tr -c '[:alnum:]' '-'
$ hello-world-
```

Why is there an extra `-` at the end and how to I get rid of it?

Comment: Try `echo -n hello/world | tr -c '[:alnum:]' '-'` (emphasis on `-n do not output the trailing newline`)

Comment: Better to suggest `printf '%s' hello/world` than `echo -n`; the latter is non-standardized and can behave differently across POSIX-compliant platforms/shells. See the APPLICATION USAGE section of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html: *It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems unless both -n (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.*

Comment: BTW, is this to make a string into a safe/valid filename? You don't need to use `echo`, `printf` *or* `tr` for the purpose at all: `old_name=hello/world; new_name=${old_name//[^[:alnum:]]/-}; echo "$new_name"` does the trick without newline literals being involved in the process (and without the expense of `fork()`ing off a bunch of subshells to run a pipeline).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be obvious that `echo` prints a `\n` at the end of each string. Since with the `-c`, you are looking to replace characters which are *not* part of `[:alnum:]`.  Since the new-line is also not part of a valid alphanumeric character, it also gets substituted.

In such situations where you are unsure which "magical" character is present or gets substituted, do a `hexdump` to see within the string. You could see the `\n` at the end.

```
echo hello/world | hexdump -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o   /   w   o   r   l   d  \n
000000c
```

So to avoid such instances of new-line and other shell meta-characters messing with your replacement string, always use `printf`:

```
printf '%s' 'hello/world' | tr -c '[:alnum:]' '-'
```

Comment: Another option is to use `tr -c '[:alnum:]\n' '-'`, adding newlines to the set of characters which aren't substituted.